# Debian MySQL Server doesn't start anymore

Tags: mysql, sql, debian

I installed and tried to configure MySQL Server on Debian. After I restarted the Service it crashed and I couldn't start it again.

Her is the following Service Status output:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-06-01 19:23:14 CEST; 3min 18s ago
  Process: 11112 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 11077 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2845 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 01 19:23:14 h2836596.stratoserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 01 19:23:14 h2836596.stratoserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 01 19:23:14 h2836596.stratoserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 01 19:23:14 h2836596.stratoserver.net systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jun 01 19:23:14 h2836596.stratoserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 01 19:23:14 h2836596.stratoserver.net systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Jun 01 19:23:14 h2836596.stratoserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 01 19:23:14 h2836596.stratoserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

---EDIT SECTION:---

Output of `dpkg -l | grep mysql`:

```
ii  mysql-client                  5.7.26-1debian9                amd64        MySQL Client meta package depending on latest version
ii  mysql-common                  5.8+1.0.2                      all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ii  mysql-community-client        5.7.26-1debian9                amd64        MySQL Client
ii  mysql-community-server        5.7.26-1debian9                amd64        MySQL Server
ii  mysql-server                  5.7.26-1debian9                amd64        MySQL Server meta package depending on latest version
rc  php7.0-mysql                  7.0.33-0+deb9u3                amd64        MySQL module for PHP
```

Output of `service mysql start`:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please run this as root:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld
```

does it start ? if it's not - what does it say?

Comment: ```-bash: ./usr/sbin/mysqld: file or directory not found```

but how can I fix that?

Comment: please post output of: dpkg -l | grep mysql

Comment: please try this: dpkg -l | grep maria; apt-get install -f;  journalctl -u mysql

Comment: I fixed it xD the problem was the file ```/etc/my.cnf``` but now I can't connect to the server from my home PC xD the Server is not local btw.

Comment: does mysql bind only on local port? ss -t -a | grep mysql

Comment: or: netstat -anpo | grep mysql

Comment: Output ```ss -t -a | grep mysql```: ```LISTEN     0      80        :::mysql                   :::*```

Comment: Output ```netstat -anpo | grep mysql```: ```tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      12574/mysqld         aus (0.00/0/0) unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     HÖRT         1815319612 12574/mysqld         /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     VERBUNDEN     1815287233 12574/mysqld```

Comment: how do you try to connect to the mysql server? Please post command and it's output. When you do this from your home PC: telnet <name or ip your mysql server > 3306  what do you see ?

Comment: btw, please ensure you do have this : bind-address = 0.0.0.0    in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf and restart mysql if you did not have it.

Comment: I did but it dosn't work :( I tryed to connect with SQLyog with the Host Address, Passwort, Port (default) and the user password. ```Error 1130 Host 'My_DOMAIN_NAME' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.```

Comment: supposing that you connect under root user - you need to ensure that the one is allowed to connect from network. you can check it this way: login to mysql localy ( like type mysql -u root -p <password you know>; in mysql console issue this: select user,host from user; if you see something like:
| root          | localhost |
then you need to change localhost to IP where from you want to connect

Comment: gat it. it works now xD user rights were set wrong xD